# Sysvolcheck returns error on backup DC upon each replication

Tags: 20.04, samba, rsync, active-directory, samba4

I have two DCs in my Samba AD with sysvol replication via rsync set up to run every 5 minutes.

On the PDC, `samba-tool ntacl sysvolcheck` returns no errors.

On the BDC, `samba-tool ntacl sysvolcheck` returns this error:

```
ERROR(<class 'samba.provision.ProvisioningError'>): uncaught exception - ProvisioningError: VFS ACL on sysvol directory /var/lib/samba/sysvol/<my domain> O:LAG:BAD:(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;LA)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;LG)(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;BG)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;BU)(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;BA)(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;BA)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;LG)(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;BG)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;BU)(A;;0x001f01ff;;;BA)(A;;0x001f01ff;;;LA)(A;;0x001200a9;;;WD)(A;OICIIO;0x001f01ff;;;CO)(A;OICIIO;;;;CG)(A;OICIIO;;;;WD) does not match expected value O:LAG:BAD:P(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;BA)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;SO)(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;SY)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;AU) from provision
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 186, in _run
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/ntacl.py", line 453, in run
    provision.checksysvolacl(samdb, netlogon, sysvol,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1896, in checksysvolacl
    raise ProvisioningError('%s ACL on sysvol directory %s %s does not match expected value %s from provision' % (acl_type(direct_db_access), dir_path, fsacl_sddl, SYSVOL_ACL))
```

I can run `sysvolreset` on the BDC which fixes the problem, but then after 5 minutes when the rsync job finishes replication the error returns on the BDC once again.

And during all this the PDC still returns no errors. It seems like something going on exclusively on the BDC's end.

As far as I can see, this isn't really causing any problems...group policies still work on the domain. Should I just let this go then?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you also syncing idmap.ldb from the the first DC to the second DC ? Also can you please stop calling your DC's 'PDC' and 'BDC', it is confusing, those terms only apply to NT4-style domain controllers

Comment: Apologies, I did not know that. And yes, I have idmap.ldb synced from DC1 to DC2 via rsync.